# Start-job powershell visible effect GUI

Tags: powershell, user-interface, start-job

I would like to know how i can launch a job and have visible effect on my GUI ? 
for example, i wait the end of a process, here "mspaint", And i start a job whitch move my image from 20px every second. When i do my "`get-job`" i have the completed state, but my image don't move.

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$Image = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("$PSScriptRoot\11.png") 
$Image1 = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("$PSScriptRoot\10.png") 

function CreateForm {

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = " - test - "
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,400)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.ShowInTaskbar = $False
$form.ControlBox = $True
$form.Topmost = $True
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.AutoSize = $False
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.Opacity = 1
$Form.BackgroundImage = $Image


$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,20) 
$label.Image = $image1;
$Label.ForeColor = "white"
$Label.BackColor = "Transparent"
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::bold)
$Label.Font = $Font
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,20)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::bold)
$OKButton.Width="156"
$OKButton.Height="40"
$Form.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$OKButton.Add_Click({


$job = Start-Job -name "Process" {
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,10) 
$Form.refresh
Start-Sleep -s 1
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(60,10) 
$Form.refresh
Start-Sleep -s 1
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,10) 
$Form.refresh
}


Do
{
Write-Host "Processes exist"
$proc = Get-Process
start-sleep 1
} While ($proc.name -contains "mspaint")
Write-Host "Processes not exist"
})

$form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

}

CreateForm
```

Have you any idea ?
Best regards

Comment: "When i do my `get-job`" - you're not calling `Get-Job` at any point in the code you've provided

Comment: `Start-Job` is a new process. So: 1) You need to explicitly pass every variable, you want to use here, nothing implicitly shared. 2) You are not able to reference live objects from job, since them serialized/deserialized when passed thru process boundary.

Comment: If you want to run processes in the background as a separate thread you should check out [this site](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/) for a good guide to creating a threaded script, it specifically addresses running things in the background and showing a progress bar that doesn't go 'Not Responding'.